# Synchronize 5 ListBoxes together

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi-2009

im working on a little Project right now and i want to synchronize 5 listBoxes scrolling together. The names of the listboxes are:

```
KidList
PointList
NoteList
CommentList
CommentListKid
```

How can i do it?

Comment: In what sense do you want the listboxes to be "synchronized" when they scroll?

Comment: When you scroll down in one of the listboxes, the other ones are going with it.

Comment: @Igerbam: Do they all contain the same number of items?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for a tListBox with 5 columns.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try the following technique.

First, add a private field

```
  private
    SyncBoxes: TArray<TListBox>;
```

to your form and initialise it when the form is created:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SyncBoxes := [ListBox1, ListBox2, ListBox3, ListBox4];
end;
```

Then define the following interposer class:

```
type
  TListBox = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TListBox)
  strict private
    procedure Sync;
  protected
    procedure WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll); message WM_VSCROLL;
    procedure CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand); message CN_COMMAND;
    procedure WMMouseWheel(var Message: TWMMouseWheel); message WM_MOUSEWHEEL;
  end;
```

implemented as

```
procedure TListBox.CNCommand(var Message: TWMCommand);
begin
  inherited;
  if Message.NotifyCode = LBN_SELCHANGE then
    Sync;
end;

procedure TListBox.Sync;
var
  LB: TListBox;
begin
  for LB in Form1.SyncBoxes do
    if LB <> Self then
      LB.TopIndex := Self.TopIndex;
end;

procedure TListBox.WMMouseWheel(var Message: TWMMouseWheel);
begin
  inherited;
  Sync;
end;

procedure TListBox.WMVScroll(var Message: TWMVScroll);
begin
  inherited;
  Sync;
end;
```

Of course, in a real app you would refactor this.

The result is possibly good enough:

[image: Video of four synchronised list boxes being scrolled.]

The list box's scrolling animation makes synchronisation a little bit delayed, however.

Comment: but can you still enter different variables?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "variables". You can name your listboxes anything you like, and they don't have to contain the same items. But of course they need to contain the same *number* of items -- otherwise, synchronised scrolling isn't possible in the most obvious sense.

Comment: okay good. The number of items is always the same. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Igerbam: No problem!